# Timing issues with socket Java I/O

Tags: java, sockets, networking, io

Trying to get how Java sockets operate. A question is: what can you do simultaneously if you are using socket Java API, and what happens if we send and read data with some delay?

1. READ & WRITE at once. If one socket-client connected to one spcket-server, can they BOTH read and write at the same time? As far as I understand, TCP protocol is full-duplex, so theoretically socket should be able to read and write at one, but we have to create two threads for bot client and server. Am I right?
2. WRITE to N clients at once. If several socket-clients connected to one socket-server, can server read several clients at one moment, can server write to several clients at one moment?
   If maximum possible physical speed rate of NetworkCard is 1kbyte/sec and 5 clients are connected, which speed is it possible to write with to one client?
3. How can I implement sequential sending of data in both directions? I mean I want to send N bytes from server to client, then M bytes from client to server, then N from server to client etc. The problem is if any of the two sides has written something to the channel, the other side will stop reading that data (read() == -1) only if channel is closed, which means that we cannot reuse it and have to open another connection. Or, may be, we should place readers and writers to different threads which do their job with read() and write() until connection is closed?
4. Imagine we have a delay between calling write(); flush() on one side, and calling read() on the other side. During the delay - where the written data would be stored? Would it be transmitted? What is the max size of that "delayed" data to be stored somewhere "between"?

Comment: I hope you find someone that can answer your question.  It will take a LOT of time due to its scope.  In a nutshell, you are asking about thread concurrency (remember that a single thread can only do one thing at a time) as well as how a `Socket` behaves for certain cases which is platform dependent.  I am too lazy to write that all up.  :)

Comment: Still thanks for trying, MadConan. Sure I will find info about concurrency by myself, but can you recommend something to read about Java networking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Correct. If you're using blocking I/O, you'll need a reader thread and a writer thread for each `Socket` connection.
2. You could use a single thread to write to N clients at once, but you run the risk of blocking on a write. I won't address the writing speeds here, as it would depend on several things, but obviously the cumulative writing speed to all clients would be under 1kbps.
3. Yes, you'll need 2 threads, you can't do this with a single thread (or you could, but as you said yourself, you'd need to constantly open and close connections).
4. It would be stored in a buffer somewhere. Depending on your code it could be in a Buffered stream, or the socket's own buffer. I believe the default buffer size of `BufferedOutputStream` is 8K, and the socket's own buffer would depend on the environment. It shouldn't really be of importance though, the streaming quality of TCP/IP removes the need to think about buffers unless you really need to do fine-tuning.